# How to update a view of row item without touching other views of the row in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I am want to change a view of a row of recyclerview without changing other views. I tried doing through notifyItemChanged, but the problem is that in my adapter I am making a service call in onBindViewHolder method and when notifyDatasetChanged is fired the service is also called again with it. I don't want to call the service, I just want to update a view of that row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. Call [notifyItemChanged(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))
2. Don't fire Service when binding your ViewHolder :)